# Set $A$ not closed under $\star$ then $A$ not a group under $\star$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am currently doing some exercises. I have been through some examples of solutions in other books that questioned me. I know well that $(A,\star)$ is a group if it satisfies the following points, such as $\star$ is associative and that there are an identity element and an inverse element in $A$. I have two questions:

1) If $A$ is not closed under $\star$, do we directly conclude that $A$ itself is not a group under $\star$?

2) If $A$ is closed under $\star$, should we check whether it's a group instead of concluding directly that it's a group?

Answer (score 9):

1.) Closure is a group axiom, so yes.

2.) Closure is not the only group axiom, so yes.

Comment: Well put. +1.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

You are totally correct.

If the set isn't closed, it can't be a group. If it is closed, check the other criteria.

If all the criteria are met you have a group.

Answer (score 0):

If a set isn't closed, it is not a group. Closure is a **necessary** condition but it is **not sufficient** to conclude a set is a group.

Closure is usually one of the first things you look for. If that is satisfied, you must check the other axioms.